# What does requesting a 2d array from 2d array do in matlab

Tags: matlab

What does `a( [4 2 3; 1 2 4; 3 2 2] )` do?

```
a = [1 2 3; 2 2 3; 1 2 3];

b = a( [4 2 3; 1 2 4; 3 2 2] ); % This line

disp(b)
```

output:

```
2     2     1
1     2     2
1     2     2
```

The output seems random. I have tried to find it in the documentary but I do not know what this  is called.

Comment: It is a lot easier to understand when `a = reshape(1:9, 3, 3)`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to understand what is happening when you select a simpler value of `a`. For example,

```
> a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] * 10
a =

   10   20   30
   40   50   60
   70   80   90

> b = [1 2; 5 6]
b =

   1   2
   5   6

> a(b)
ans =

   10   40
   50   80

> a(1)
ans = 10

> a(2)
ans = 40

> a(5)
ans = 50

> a(6)
ans = 80
```

Each element of `b` is used as a [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) into `a`, and the resulting array is of the same shape as `b`.